# 0 i would like to delete a blank space when I embebbeded a TableViewCell in my ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode12.5

I need to delete the space between tableviewcell and the safe area to add a background color

[this is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdY0A.png)

this is my tableview cell and my view controller[This. is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHrOJ.png), please help

[This is what i got, i need to delete that white space 2]

Comment: Do your lateral constraints are using margins?

Comment: Eduardo Santi, thanks for your help, i resolved it

Comment: Very nice Juan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand if you are using Xcode 13. If it's true, you can remove the "top padding".

Try make like this to remove in a specific UITableView:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = .zero
```

Or make like this in AppDelegate to remove to all UITableViews:

```
UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = .zero
```

Comment: I'm using Xcode 12.5.1, and I can't use that line